# This question is about negative velocity

Tags: kinematics, velocity

So let's say I have an object moving from the points X to Y and my positive direction is to the right. Now suppose the object moves back from Y to a point W on the line between X and Y. Is the displacement for the second journey deemed to be negative? The object is not before point X. And now let's say I want to calculate that displacement with the SUVAT equation of motion: $s = ut + (1/2)at^2$. If I put the velocity to be negative, I will obtain a different answer than the actual distance travelled from Y to W. Why is that?

Comment: Is X and Y axis or position. Also , are they a point on which axis. Add more clear details to the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a usual confusion. You must take into account that there is a separation between reality and how we mathematically model reality. A distance is always possitive, that's well known. However, if we want to talk about **position**, we need a coordinate system, and ocordinates can be either possitive or negative. You must not mix position with "ditances". Both $x=+5$ and $x=-5$ are at distance $5$ units from the origin. In other words, positions are jsut coordinates, and they can have a sign.

Position:

- x) Possitive at the right side of the origin, negative at the left side.
- y) Possitive if above the origin, negative below origin

Now, what happens to velocity? In the same way, the speed is a concept that can only be possitive, but the coordinates of velocity can be negative, and ther's nothing wrong with it.

To compute the sign of velocity, you will recall the definition of velocity:

$$v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{ x_{final}-x_{initial}}{t_{final}-t_{initial}}$$

As time always flows forwards (at least in this kind of exercises) the denominator will always be possitive, so the sigh of velocity will depend on the numerator only.

So check that the numerator contains the **difference** in positions. It is $x_{final}-x_{initial}$. The numerator, and hence velocity, will be possitive as long as the final position is bigger than the initial one.

When I say bigger, I'm including negatiev values. If you go from $-9$ to $-7$, the value is "less negative", so the position is also increasing.

Consequently, you can deduce a pratical rule for velocities.

**Velocity**

- $v_x$) Possitive if moving rightwards, negative if moving leftwards.
- $v_y$) Possitive if moving upwards, negative if moving downwards

---

It is also important that you do not mix position and velocity. Position is where you are, and velocity is how fast you move away from there.

You can be far away, in Russia, for example (that's position), but moving quickly to the USA (that's velocity).

---

How to use them?

In uniform straight movement (USM), and uniformly accelerated straight movement (UASM), formulae require signs for all quantities: position, velocity and acceleration. All of them must have the signs included.

So, the first thing you must do is making a picture of your situation. Never try to do an exercise without a picture!

Once you have a shceme of what is happening, you must decide where is your origin of coordinates and what are you coordinate axes.

Once you have decided where your Reference system is, then you only have to decide signs acoording to the criteria listed above.

Tip: if possible, try to place your origin as low and leftwards as possible, so that most coordinates are possitive, in order to avoid minus signs.

---

Edit: yes, you will obtain different results if you put the signs wrong. Teh reason is that the equation

$x_{final} = x_{initial} + v\cdot t $ means that the final position is the same as the initial plus a variation. A possitive variation means increasing position, whiel a negative one means decreasing. It's not the same, you must say if the rate of change is from one side or to another, and that's what the signs are for

Comment: great answer, though i did not understand the last line...

Comment: you said ''the coordinates  of velocity'' , velocity is a vector quantity it has magnitude and direction, and position can have coordinates but how can velocity have coordinates?

Comment: Vectors do also have coordinates as soon as there is a reference frame. For example, a vector of magnitude 1 unit leftwards is (1,0)

Comment: so thats like a position vector?

Comment: so thats like a position vector?

Comment: Yes, all vectors work the same way

Answer (score 2):

Because you forgot to flip the sign of the acceleration too.

Comment: When deceleration is due to friction why would we flip the signs?

Comment: Position, velocity and acceleration are vectors.

So if you flip your reference frame x->x then both velocity and acceleration get also a minus, since they are the times derivate of x (so dx/dt-> -dx/dt, etc.)
Another way is to calculate the distance using modules, in this case s,u, t are the MODULOS of  the three quantities, so they are invariant under x->-x.

Comment: can you explain what you mean exactly i'm not getting what you mean by reference frame and what does differentiation have to do with this?

Comment: Mmmh how have you derived the equation for s=ut+a/2t^2? 
Because usually it is obtained by saying that velocity and acceleration are the derivative of the position etc. etc. But I think this is not the case